# Как разместить два горизонтальных списка друг над другом справа в header?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Мне необходимо разместить два горизонтальных списка друг над другом, уже целый день голову ломаю. Они у меня ведут себя как угодно, но только не становятся как надо.

```
.menu {
    display: inline;
    align-items: flex-start;
}
.menu-list {
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
    padding-right: 68px;
}
.contacts {
    display: inline;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
.contact-info {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
}/*текст, выделенный жирным шрифтом*/
```

Вот html:

```
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="/img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="logo-text">
    <h1>BuhOne</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-list">ГЛАВНАЯ</li>
    <li class="menu-list">УСЛУГИ</li>
    <li class="menu-list">КЛИЕНТЫ</li>
    <li class="menu-list">О КОМПАНИИ</li>
    <li class="menu-list">КОНТАКТЫ</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="contacts">
    <li class="contact-info">
      <img src="/img/phone.svg" alt="phone" class="contact-image"> 8 (111) 222-33-44
    </li>
    <li class="contact-info">
      <img src="/img/clock.svg" alt="clock" class="contact-image"> Пн-Пт 10:00-18:00
    </li>
    <li class="contact-info">
      <img src="/img/mail.svg" alt="mail" class="contact-image"> order@buhone.ru
    </li>
    <li class="contact-info">
      <img src="/img/gps (1).svg" alt="" class="contact-image"> Невский пр. 130
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

Есть лого, она слева, а эти два списка должны быть в правой части сайта.

Comment: Хотелось бы HTML посмотреть

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.menu {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
}

.menu-list {
  display: inline;
  font-family: 'Roboto', serif;
  padding-right: 68px;
}

.contacts {
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
  align-content: flex-start;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 68px;
}

.contact-info {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
```

```html
<header class="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="/img/logo.svg" alt="logo">
  </div>
  <div class="logo-text">
    <h1>BuhOne</h1>
  </div>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="menu-list">ГЛАВНАЯ</li>
    <li class="menu-list">УСЛУГИ</li>
    <li class="menu-list">КЛИЕНТЫ</li>
    <li class="menu-list">О КОМПАНИИ</li>
    <li class="menu-list">КОНТАКТЫ</li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="contacts">
    <li class="contact-info">
      <img src="/img/phone.svg" alt="phone" class="contact-image"> 8 (111) 222-33-44
    </li>
    <li class="contact-info">
      <img src="/img/clock.svg" alt="clock" class="contact-image"> Пн-Пт 10:00-18:00
    </li>
    <li class="contact-info">
      <img src="/img/mail.svg" alt="mail" class="contact-image"> order@buhone.ru
    </li>
    <li class="contact-info">
      <img src="/img/gps (1).svg" alt="" class="contact-image"> Невский пр. 130
    </li>
  </ul>
</header>
```